# Can Identify tool to return the raw values of rasters?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, arcgis-desktop

I have a raster in ArcGIS 10 SP4 set to bilinear resampling in its display properties.  When using the identify tool it returns the resampled value instead of the raw value.

Can we get the identify tool to natively return the raw value?

Comment: This may be a related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32063/how-to-get-raw-values-from-ogc-web-coverage-service-wcs-via-arcgis-for-desktop

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing **ArcGIS Idea** called **[Identify tool should return the raw grid data value as well as the smoothed value](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bwqD)** which I recommend you add your vote to.