# How to get raw values from OGC Web Coverage Service (WCS) via ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geotiff-tiff, ogc, wcs

I posted this a few days ago to the [ArcGIS Discussion Forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65021-WCS-and-raw-cell-pixel-values) but have had no response so thought I would try here as well.

I'm new to Web Coverage Services (WCS) but have found it easy to add one using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 and this service URL:

http://nsidc.org/cgi-bin/atlas_south?service=WCS&request=GetCapabilities&version=1.1.1

I add the service by Liu et al. and get a nice display.

However, when I use Identify to look at the values for any cell on the grid/coverage all Stretched Values and Pixel Values are in the range 0-255. I would expect to see 0-255 used for the Stretched Values but thought the Pixel Value would be holding raw data with values well in excess of 255.

When I export data from the WCS to a file geodatabase raster the values there are 0-255 too.

Is it possible to access the raw values held in a WCS?

(Hopefully I am just misunderstanding how to get my desired result)

NSIDC have said that their server is configured to provide data in GeoTIFF format. Their **[docs](http://nsidc.org/data/atlas/ogc_services.html)** make it appear that GeoTIFFInt16 and GeoTIFFFloat32 are both options but they suspect that the GetCoverage request generated by ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 is using a format that maps the data into an 8-bit format instead.

I do not know of an option within ArcGIS for Desktop to select the GeoTIFF format used by GetCoverage or a way to trap the GetCoverage URL that it is passing to the WCS server.

Comment: Do you know who is serving this WCS? If so, I would ask them if the raster has a colormap associated with it. If it does, the GIS Server might be serving the colormap values instead of the actual raster values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing **ArcGIS Idea** called **[Identify tool should return the raw grid data value as well as the smoothed value](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bwqD)** which I will add my vote to.